# Sun shader not working

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, shader, fragment-shader

I'm trying to get a sun shader to work, but I can't get it to work.
What I currently get is a quarter of a circle/elipsis on the lower left of my screen, that is really stuck to my screen (if I move the camera, it also moves).

All I do is render two triangles to form a screen-covering quad, with screen width and height in uniforms.

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 430 core

void main(void) {
    const vec4 vertices[6] = vec4[](
        vec4(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),

        vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    );

    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 7) uniform int screen_width;
layout(location = 8) uniform int screen_height;

layout(location = 1) uniform mat4 view_matrix;
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 light_pos = vec3(-20.0, 7.5, -20.0);

void main(void) {
    //calculate light position in screen space and get x, y components
    vec2 screen_space_light_pos = (proj_matrix * view_matrix * vec4(light_pos, 1.0)).xy;

    //calculate fragment position in screen space
    vec2 screen_space_fragment_pos = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x / screen_width, gl_FragCoord.y / screen_height);

    //check if it is in the radius of the sun
    if (length(screen_space_light_pos - screen_space_fragment_pos) < 0.1) {
        color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    else {
        discard;
    }
}
```

What I *think* it does:

- Get the position of the sun (`light_pos`) in screen space.
- Get the fragment position in screen space.
- If the distance between them is below a certain value, draw fragment with yellow color;
- Else discard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen_space_light_pos` is not yet in clip space. You've missed perspective division:

```
vec3 before_division = (proj_matrix * view_matrix * vec4(light_pos, 1.0)).xyw;
vec2 screen_space_light_pos = before_division.xy / before_division.z;
```

With common `proj_matrix` configurations, `screen_space_light_pos` will be in `[-1,1]x[-1,1]`. To match `screen_space_fragment_pos` range, you probably need to adjust `screen_space_light_pos`:

```
screen_space_light_pos = screen_space_light_pos * 0.5 + 0.5;
```

Comment: In addition you can optimize this simple shader by computing the clip space sun center once out of the shader

Comment: Strange; with your implementation `screen_space_light_pos` gives `isnan()` on both the `x` and `y` component. However `before_division` gives all correct values on the `x`, `y` and `z` components in vec3 form.

Comment: Actually it is because `before_division.z == 0`, I still have to found out why that is though.

Comment: Your code is working now, thanks a lot. Turns out I was forgetting to supply the `proj_matrix`, `view_matrix` uniforms, no clue why there was no error from GLSL/OpenGL though.